# How can I get strongly typed data/poco from a triple store/RDF graph database using C#?

Tags: c#, sparql, rdf, dotnetrdf

Currently I am using an RDF graph database (Ontotext GraphDB), which I query using a SPARQL query via dotnetRDF and C#.

Via the `SparqlResultSet` I can access the data and create a typed object/poco, but I am looking for some magic like Dapper, but then for RDF databases. Create a query, execute it and get typed data as a result.

Is there something like that, or functionality to build poco's from a result? I am not tied to dotnetRDF, an alternative is also an option.

Answer (score 2):

[RomanticWeb](https://github.com/MakoLab/RomanticWeb) might do what you need. Unfortunately the project site appears to be down at the moment, but the packages are all available via NuGet.

Comment: Thanks, I am investigating it. It is unfortunate that the project page is indeed offline, and the last commit is over 5 years ago, so not actively maintained. But your remark has also sparkled a new search result: https://trinity-rdf.net/, which I am also investigating..

Answer (score 1):

You may also have a look at [Iride](https://github.com/giacomociti/iride#sparqlqueryprovider). It is an F# library but can be used from C# via a thin F# project which does not require any knowledge of the F# language, just a series of type declarations like:

```
type Q = SparqlQueryProvider<"SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?IRI_p $INT }">
```

So you can write SPARQL queries and the type provider will create a method (Q.GetText) to pass input parameters and a POCO wrapper (Q.Result) for the result variables.